# Objective C-OSX How to change color of NSTableViewCell when selecting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

there are 3 cell in my table view
my table is view base table
my requirement is when i select any cell(click on any row) text color and background color of that(selected cell)  table view cell change

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution could be using `NSTableViewDelegate` declared as [tableViewSelectionDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableViewSelectionDidChange:). Inside it use the property [selectedRowIndexes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableView/selectedRowIndexes), which will provide the currently selected rows. Then customize those cell as you want (changing the background color or whatever else).

**NB :: don't forget to clear the cell's which are not in the `selectedRowIndexes`, otherwise deselcting won't change their state**